# NetBeans - how to set default startup Maven module in multi-module maven project?

Tags: maven, netbeans-7

I'm looking for the way to configure Netbeans workspace for multi-module maven project to always start some module when pressing CTRL+F5 (Debug main project). Being within maven project this shortcut always starts the project whose source file is currently being open. This is annoying - to start debugger i always have to either switch to some source file from the 'main' module or find that module in project explorer (huge sub-tree) and right click -> Debug (both are regular useless waste of time )

Similar question is about re-running last unit test - i can't find shortcut for this, but i see related bug report is not addressed since Aug 2010: http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=189113.

Comment: I have a similar question related to Build of master project when in sub-project.  This not a direct answer, but a work around for the question.  If a project is Run or Debugged once - from then on it will appear as a drop-down item against the related (Run, Debug) ToolBar icon. Sadly (for me) there is no drop-down behaviour on Build icon, but may ease

Answer (score 0):

You have to put that action specified in the nbactions.xml like:

```
<action>
    <actionName>debug</actionName>
    <packagings>
        <packaging>jar</packaging>
    </packagings>
    <goals>  
        <goal>org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec</goal>
    </goals>
    <properties>
        <jpda.listen>maven</jpda.listen> 
        <exec.args>-classpath %classpath com.domain.package.Main start</exec.args>
        <exec.executable>java</exec.executable>
        <exec.workingdir>./content</exec.workingdir>
    </properties>
</action>
```

So it will excecute the Main file in a module of your proyect.

If you want to excecute a Main java file of a dependency project you must include this plugin entry:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId> 
            <executions>  
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/dependency-jars/</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
        </plugin>
```

This will allow your maven project to copy all dependencies you need to your target during packaging phase. Then use this other plugin entry for making the Main class you need accessible:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>com.domain.package.Main</mainClass>
                        <classpathPrefix>dependency-jars/</classpathPrefix>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

You may change the folder where dependency jars will be or even make it a property in the pom.xml of your parent maven project.